# jQuery applying style when loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning jQuery by playing around with some basic concepts.

What I am trying to do is apply some style to button element (id) when the page is loaded.
Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/L2Ssq/3/).

The following is the script and I cannot spot any issue with it.

```
$(document).ready(function ({
    $('#jc').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Does it have anything to do with jsFiddle setting or am I missing something crucial.

Comment: It's `function() {` not `function({`

Comment: Thanks, I should have looked at it more carefully and first checked with jshint of jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code works if you add `()`.

But the background-color in your fiddle is not shown, however, the CSS is applied. Change to "color" instead of "background-color" and you see that your CSS style is applied. You rather have to look at the CSS itself and how it is applied to button elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#jc').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It was an easy miss. Tried with "color" and now it overwrites. I guess with "background-color" Bootstrap default style rule wins over mine.

Answer (score 3):

`function ({` should be `function (){`

Comment: Also, style should be a separate concern from script, therefore put this style into a CSS file, and apply a `class` to the element instead.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the parenthesis.

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/L2Ssq/6/

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('#jc').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your code, here is the correct version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

});
```

With your version, you are - kind of - trying to pass a JSON object into the function parameter line.

Answer (score 0):

You have the incorrect syntax in jQuery code. replace with:

```
$(document).ready(function (){ //change here
    $('#jc').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```